# UTF8 characters on HTTP Headers

Tags: http

There are some restriction of character encoding on headers HTTP?

I'm sending a response with a custom Header ***"X-Msj: Búho"***, but on my console I get ***X-Msj: "BÃºho"***.

Comment: What’s sending the response? What’s reading it and putting it in your console?

Comment: It's a Go server: w.Header().set("X-Msj", "Búho"). Go encoding using UTF-8. I see the response on the Firefox's console.

Comment: The content is encoding successfully with utf8, but no the headers.